# Update android internal test app in developer console

Tags: google-apps, developer-console

We have an app launched in google playstore.I made some changes to the app and uploaded a new version to the internal test track. While doing the internal test, we identified an issue and i wanted to update internal test app "with the same version number". Since the app is not released to Alpha or beta test, is it possible to update it? If so how do i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem, this is what I found out:

According to the Docs (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=de) the version code must be higher for an update.

Just increment it, as it is not shown to the user anyways. The release-name, which is shown to the user, can stay the same.

So to update, I tried the following:

- On the internal test track, click 'Manage'
- Inside of this track, click 'Create Release'
- Set everything up as you want (there is a copy from previous release option at the bottom), just make sure the version code has been incremented, so you can upload your apk. Then, check and release the app.

Once you are done, previous bundles are no longer provided, and existing testers *should* be able to update.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: as the app is already uploaded in the internal test and may take time to process update, and if again developer wants to replace so he doesn't have to wait for previous internal test release to get live. What should be done in this case?

Comment: I'm facing a weird issue. I uploaded an internal test app with version code 111 and current production version is 33. However when I clicked direct link to version 111, the Play Store says "This is an old version (111) of this app."